# How to tell a difference between a SimpleFilletFeatureData with simple radius and one with a chamfer cross section?

Tags: solidworksapi

I need to find all Fillet and Chamfer Features and check if any of them is breaking any of the 12 boundary edges of the rectangular initial base shape. The macro will create a report file. The report file should also contain the fillet radius and / or chamfer parameters.
The bit I am struggling with is telling apart a Fillet feature with a radius from a Fillet feature with a chamfer cross section. Chamfer command creates a Fillet feature with a chamfer profile if an edge is selected.

If I understand it correctly, this is controlled by ConicRhoType parameter of the FilletFeature3 method. This is fine when creating a new feature, but I can not find any ISimpleFilletFeatureData2 interface property or method that can tell me what the ConicRhoType is of an existing feature. The only method containing any reference to Rho is the GetConicRhoOrRadius method. It tells me the size of the feature, but I am not any wiser if this is a radius or a size of the chamfer profile. Any advice?

Comment: The `ISimpleFilletFeatureData` class is for fillets only. If the user specifies a conic rho type with a minimum value, there is still some curvature on the face. If there is a Chamfer in the feature tree, its data will be of type `IChamferFeatureData2`